# Concealment at the boundary of Oscuring Mist

Tags: pathfinder-1e, concealment

[Obscuring Mist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/obscuring-mist) says

> The vapor obscures all sight, including darkvision, beyond 5 feet. A
>   creature 5 feet away has concealment (attacks have a 20% miss chance).

Let's say A & B are standing beside each other (each in their own square) with A just inside the mist and B just outside of it. Do they both have concealment from one another? Just A? Just B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To determine whether your target has [concealment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Concealment) from your ranged attack, choose a corner of your square. If any line from this corner to any corner of the target's square passes through a square or border that provides concealment, the target has concealment.
>
> When making a melee attack against an adjacent target, your target has concealment if his space is entirely within an effect that grants concealment. When making a melee attack against a target that isn't adjacent to you, use the rules for determining concealment from ranged attacks.

A has concealment against B's attacks, whether they are ranged or melee.  B does not have concealment from A's attacks, whether they are ranged or melee.

For melee, this is because A's space is entirely inside a concealment-granting effect (since Obscuring Mist fills the square instead of just providing concealment at the borders) and B's is not.  For ranged, this is because A can choose a corner on the border and draw lines to all of B's corners without going back into the Mist's space, but two of B's lines to A's corners must pass through the Mist space A is standing in.

Comment: I am curious do you have any source reference to support this? Logic says if they are not 5' within the mist they do not have the full concealment of the mist and their view out from the mist is equally obscured compared to the person outside looking into the mist. Light still travels through an obscuring mist so illumination is not the discerning factor.

Comment: My comment that was here previously was...  technically correct for many forms of concealment but not accurately describing obscuring mist.  If you are in the mist, you have concealment against adjacent creatures and total concealment against creatures further away.  The way its written seems to imply that if you're sharing a space with a creature, you don't have concealment against that creature;  that's pretty ambiguous, though, and I'd urge GMs to apply common sense here depending on the creatures themselves.